# A typical operation on a generic function

Tags: java, python, generics

I was recently learning generics in Java and a question came in my mind that Python programmers can relate to. All I did was to create a generic Java function which should return a string and take two parameters, "p1 and p2" of different (or similar) generic types. But the tricky thing is I want to return the value of p1 if p1 is of type String, else a general String message... A simple Python implementation of this code will be:

```
def func1(a, b):
    if type(a) == str:
        return a
    else:
        return 'bye'

func1(2, 5)             # Output: 'bye'
func1("hi", 5)          # Output: 'hi'
```

I tried the same on a Java function, but it seems to give an error which by my observations can only be rectified if it is forcefully (rather unwantedly, since the obj1 is already checked for being a type of string)  typecasted into String:

```
public static <T, T2> String func3(T obj1, T2 obj2) {
    if (obj1.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("String")){
        return obj1;       // <--error    // (String)obj1; <-- is working
    }
    else {
        return "bye";
    }
}
```

So, what is being wrong here? Is it somewhat related to the "ducktyping" feature of Python, and not possible in Java? Or am I using the wrong functions for getting the desired class name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is related to the fact that Python is dynamically typed.

Although you checked the type of `obj1` here:

```
if (obj1.getClass().getSimpleName()=="String"){
```

The compiler forgets about this when it sees the return statement. It will insist that `obj1` is of type `T` but not `String`, so `obj1` can't be returned.

The solution for this is, as you pointed out, cast `obj1` to `String`. Casting is like saying to the compiler, "I am sure this is a string!"

P.S.: You can check if an object is a string by simply doing:

```
if (obj1 instanceof String)
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually in Java you can check the type of an object using `instanceof`:

```
 someObject instanceof Type
```

is `true` if the object is a `Type` or a subclass of `Type`.

Otherwise, you can do something like this:

```
 someObject.getClass().equals(Type.class)
```

is `true` only if the object is a `Type`

In your case you can use both:

```
obj1 instanceof String
```

or

```
obj1.getClass().equals(String.class)
```

But I suggest the first solution as in Java is the most used.

In your case I would write a method like this:

```
public static String func3(T obj1, T2 obj2) {
    if(obj1 instanceof String) {
        return (String)obj1;       
    }
    else {
        return "obj1 not a String";
    }
}
```

Comment: But you still need the typecast.

Comment: Sure, however I think that the question was more related to the type comparison. Anyway I will update my solution.